# how to fix the 504 error in my load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform and I am trying to create a simple structure with one ALB 2 servers with a simple app and one db instance, but I get a 504 error when accesing to the ALB`s DNS whoch checking the amazon documentation means `The load balancer established a connection to the target but the target did not respond before the idle timeout period elapsed.` I have gone over the code 100 times but I cannot find the mistake. This is my alb config:

```
#ASG
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "web-lc" {
  name            = "web-lc"
  image_id        = "ami-0fc970315c2d38f01"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2-webServers-sg.id]
  key_name        = "practica_final_kp"
  user_data       = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              sudo yum update -y
              sudo yum install -y docker
              sudo service docker start
              sudo docker run -d --name rtb -p 8080:8080 vermicida/rtb
              EOF

}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ec2-web-asg" {
  name                 = "ec2-web-asg"
  max_size             = 2
  min_size             = 2
  force_delete         = true
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.web-lc.name
  vpc_zone_identifier  = [aws_subnet.public-subnet1.id, aws_subnet.public-subnet2.id]

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "ec2-web-asg"
    propagate_at_launch = "true"
  }
}

#ALB
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "tg-alb" {
  name        = "tg-alb"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "instance"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.final-vpc.id
}

resource "aws_alb" "web-alb" {
  name            = "web-alb"
  internal        = false
  subnets         = [aws_subnet.public-subnet1.id, aws_subnet.public-subnet2.id]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb-sg.id]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.web-alb.id
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.tg-alb.id
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.ec2-web-asg.id
  alb_target_group_arn   = aws_alb_target_group.tg-alb.arn
}
```

this is the security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2-webServers-sg" {
  name   = "ec2-webServers-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.final-vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "APP"
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  }

  egress {
    description = "SQL"
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.10.0/24", "10.0.20.0/24"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "F-web-servers-sg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your service on the EC2 instance is running on port `8080`, but your target group is pointing to port `80`. You need to change the target group port to `8080`.

There could also be a problem with security groups and VPC Network ACLs blocking the traffic, but you didn't include the definition of `aws_security_group.ec2-webServers-sg.id`  in your question.

Comment: thanks for answering I have added the security group I changed it to port 8080 and now I get the site cannot be reached message...should I also have to change the port for the alb listener? I guess no but just to make sure...

Comment: No the ALB listener should stay port 80. I suggest logging into the EC2 server and verifying the app is running by doing something like `curl http://localhost:8080`